# Sequelize connection with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing issue on connection of SEQUELIZE(mysql) with NodeJs. Though connection is established but models are not properly configured. I have use this approach --

`./config/sequelize-conn.js`

```
'use strict';
var sequelize  = function (config, Sequelize) {
var sql = new Sequelize(config.mysql.db, config.mysql.user, config.mysql.pass, {
    host:        config.mysql.host,
    dialect:     'mysql', //|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql'
    pool:        {
        max:  5,
        min:  0,
        idle: 10000
    },
    //logging:     true,
    underscored: true
});
sql
    .sync({force: true})
    //.authenticate()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully with mysql.');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Connection with mysql failed.', error);
    });
return sql;
};
module.exports = sequelize;
```

`//server.js`

```
var sequelize     = require('sequelize');
var sqlConnection = require('./config/sequelize-conn')(config, sequelize);
```

I wish to directly use model this way ..

`models/HotelGroup.js`

```
var Sequelize  = require('sequelize');
var sequelize  = require('../../config/sequelize-conn');
var HotelGroup = Sequelize.define('hotel_chains', {
    id:         {
        type:          Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull:     false,
        primaryKey:    true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    hotel_name: {
        type:      Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    hotel_code: {
        type:      Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    status:     {
        type:         Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull:    false,
        defaultValue: '1'
    }
}, {
    tableName:       'hotel_chains',
    timestamps:      false,
    paranoid:        true  // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});
module.exports = HotelGroup;
```

**Its giving me error that sequelize.define is not a function.**

Though connection is establishing but when I try to access any model in service file using require. It breaks with this error message. Where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the instance of sequelize, not the class. So `sequelize.define` *not* `Sequelize.define`.

Also, you need to instantiate it properly: `var sequelize = new Sequelize(...)`

Comment: Check my file `./config/sequelize-conn.js` I have instantiated it properly. & for `sequelize.define`. I have tried with that also. I am getting same error.